# Mandatory field check on a data input sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a data entry sheet in Excel which consists of 3 columns: A field title (e.g. name, part no, etc.) (Column B), the data entry field (column C), and a check mark field which marks a mandatory field (column D). When I initially incorporated the code into my workbook, it was working correctly.  Now it is not working, the only change I can think of that would impact is the number of data entry rows has increased.

I have already run through debug and the variables appear to be grabbing the correct data. This is the section of the code which looks at the mandatory fields.

```
Else

  'cells to copy from Input sheet - some contain formulas
  Set myCopy = inputWks.Range("EntryData")

  lRec = inputWks.Range("CurrRec").Value
  lRecRow = lRec + 2

  With inputWks
      Set myTest = myCopy.Offset(0, 1)

      If Application.Count(myTest) > 0 Then
          MsgBox "Please fill in all the cells!"
          Exit Sub
      End If
  End With
```

The rest of the If/Else statement is working correctly, however the code does not appear to be checking against the mandatory field column.

"EntryData" is a named range which includes all of the data from column C (data entry column)

Comment: what value is `myCopy`? After `Set myCopy = inputWks.Range("EntryData")` enter `Debug.Print myCopy` Is this how many entries you have?

Comment: `If Application.Count(myTest) > 0 Then` Should this not be `If len(Trim(myTest.Value))= 0 Then`

Comment: What is the meaning of "it's not working"? Do you mean it asks to fill data every time it runs? Your code would give such a message if there is any number anywhere in range "DataEntry". If you want to find missing data you might try If Application.Count(myTest) = 0

Comment: @alowflyingpig adding this code is just producing type mismatch errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So mystery solved, I missed a hidden helper column, which the

```
  Set myTest = myCopy.Offset(0, 1)
```

line should have been referencing, the offset should have been (0, 2) and in column E the following formula was needed:

```
 =IF(E5="","",IF(D5="",1,""))
```

Which puts up a 1 if a cell marked as mandatory in column D is not filled in Column C, which explains why this line;

```
If Application.Count(myTest) > 0 Then
```

is looking for a number greater than 0.

Thank you to those who commented with advice!